# What should be the outcome of this ontology?

Tags: logic, owl, ontology, discrete-mathematics, reasoning

I am learning web ontology and Description logic.
I came across this and was quite confused about what should be the answer:

This is the knowledge base. Where Parent(X,Y) means X is  parent of Y.

```
Parent(X,Y).
Parent(Y,Z).
Parent(X,Z).
Parent(Z,M).
Manager(Y).
¬Manager(M).
```

Does these facts imply fact:

```
X∈(∃Parent.(Manager⊓∃Parent.¬Manager))
```

P.S this is not homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no.

What can be inferred:

`∃Parent.⊤                      (X has some parent, namely Y and Z)
∃Parent.Manager                (X has some parent that is a manager, namely Y but not Z)
∃Parent.(Manager ⊓ ∃Parent.⊤)  (X has some parent that is a manager and has a parent, namely Y)`

`Z` is not a manager, thus you could only infer

`∃Parent.∃Parent.⊤              (X has some parent (Y and Z) that has a parent
∃Parent.∃Parent.¬Manager       (X has some parent (Z) that has a parent (M) which is not a manager)`